# Evidence for a 2-component framework of visual attention distribution

Tags: perception, vision, attention

As part of my bachelor thesis on eyetracking-based gaze guidance, I've done quite a bit of reading (again) on visual attention and visual attention distribution. What caught my attention (haha) earlier this morning is a section about a two-part framework for visual attention distribution.

Ref. to the article:

> Laurent Itti, Christof Koch (2000). A saliency-based search mechanism
>   for overt and covert shifts of visual attention.

Page 2, left column, second paragraph from the top, it states:

> *Much evidence has accumulated in favor of a two component framework for
>   the control of where in a visual scene attention is deployed
>   [References here]: a bottom-up, fast, primitive mechanism that biases
>   the observer towards selecting stimuli based on their saliency (most
>   likely encoded in terms of center-surround mechanisms) and a second
>   slower, top-down mechanism with variable selection criteria, which
>   directs the ‘spotlight of attention’ under cognitive, volitional
>   control. Whether visual consciousness can be reached by either
>   saliency-based or top-down attentional selection or by both remains
>   controversial.*

With this article being from 2000 and pretty much every reference to support this dated between 1980 and 1998, is there any current work (2000+) to support this model, or has it even been refuted?

There are quite a lot of visual attention distribution models centering around saliency as the core parameter that seem to fit pretty well, but what about the second component of the framework that is suggested here?

Looking forward to some interesting answers. I can provide additional references if needed.